# Device to quickly and cheaply scan checks

Tags: scanner

I work for a non-profit in Europe that receives a lot of donations by check. For our fiscal records, we want to keep a scan of each check that comes in but with something that doesn't obstruct our workflow. Any suggestions?

For example, I thought of the [ChefXpress CX30](https://www.digitalcheck.com/product/remote-deposit-scanner-cx30/) but it doesn't work with regular scanning software (a proprietary protocol) and I can't seem to find software that works with it. There are solutions like Doxie and Epson doc scanners but I don't know how reliable they are and if they allow for scanning a bunch of docs at once.

Thanks!